# Python Simple Range and Bearing Calculator using Complex Numbers

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I have just written this code that takes an initial coordinate and returns a new vector depending on a user-supplied range and bearing.

The calculation of the new position is done using Complex Numbers. I am sure there are easier ways to do this, but I wanted to play around with complex numbers. Any thoughts on these would be great.

The calculator is in a file called GenGeo, as this is where I keep lots of little modules like this that may be called again in other programs.

I have used `**kwargs` for `a_e` and `a_n` as these may not be required by the user. However, I have never really used `*args` and `**kwargs` before, so presume that I may have messed something up here.

This is the calculator module in GenGeo:

```py
class CmO:
    """
    This class will contain specific code that is required to run a C-O calculation
    This includes range and bearing calc
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        :param a_e: initial easting
        :param a_n: initial northing
        """
        self.a_e = kwargs.get('a_e', None)
        self.a_n = kwargs.get('a_n', None)

    def complex_randb(self, r, b):
        """
        An equation that using imaginary numbers to calculate the coordinates of a new
        point from a range and bearing of an old point
        :param r: range from original coordinate to new coordinate
        :param b: bearing from original coordinate to new coordinate
        """

        # -b is required as geodetic bearings are opposite to mathematical bearings
        t = complex(cos(radians(-b)), sin(radians(-b))) * complex(0, r)
        delta_easting = t.real
        delta_northing = t.imag

        if self.a_e and self.a_n is not False:

            new_easting = self.a_e + delta_easting
            new_northing = self.a_n + delta_northing

            return new_easting, new_northing

        else:
            return delta_easting, delta_northing
```

and this is the program that I have used to call it:

```py
from GenGeo import CmO

initial_E = 100
initial_N = 100
input_range = 3
input_bearing = 310


a = CmO(a_e=initial_E, a_n=initial_N)
nE, nN = a.complex_randb(input_range, input_bearing)

print(f"The delta Easting and Northing are {round(nE, 3)}mE and {round(nN, 3)}mN")
```

Next project is writing something to calculate the range and bearing between two points

Any thoughts or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are the initial easting and northing optional? Removing them from the second snippet results in an error.

Comment: @TedBrownlow - Very good point, oops. I have updated the code so that this is now actually an optional statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Keyword-only parameters

You are not using `**kwargs` correctly.  `**kwargs` should be used when you can accept any number of keywords, but you don't know what the keywords will be, such as dictionary creation.  If you only accept 2 keyword parameters, you should list those keyword parameters explicitly:

```
    def __init__(self, *, a_e=None, a_n=None):
        """
        :param a_e: initial easting
        :param a_n: initial northing
        """

        self.a_e = a_e
        self.a_n = a_n
```

That `*` marks the end of positional parameters.  `a_e` and `a_n` can be specified by keyword only.  Since both default to `None`, both are optional.  Any other keywords is reject with an error message, instead of silently being ignored.

## Operator Precedence

```
        if self.a_e and self.a_n is not False:
```

This statement does not do what you think it does.  `is not` is higher precedence than `and`, so it reads:

```
        if self.a_e and (self.a_n is not False):
```

thus, if `a_n` is never given as `False`, the result of `is not` will be `True`, and the `and` will always result in the truthiness of `a_e` only.

You probably intended the evaluation to be:

```
        if (self.a_e and self.a_n) is not False:
```

which tests the truthiness of both `a_e` and `a_n`.  Sort of.  There are very few ways of getting something for which `is not False` is not true out of that expression.  The only way to get to the `else` expression is if `a_e == False`, or if `a_e` held a truthy value and `a_n == False`.  Again, since if the values are not given, they are defaulted to `None`, and since `None and None` evaluates to `None`, and `None is not False` is a true statement, the `if` clause would be executed.

So you probably wanted to write:

```
        if self.a_e is not None and self.a_n is not None:
```

## Why not Zero?

If you used `0` as the default for `a_n` and `a_e`, then

```
            new_easting = self.a_e + delta_easting
            new_northing = self.a_n + delta_northing
```

`new_easting` would simply become `delta_easting` and `new_northing` would become `delta_northing`, and you could always do the addition and return `new_easting, new_northing.

```
    def __init__(self, *, a_e=0, a_n=0):
        """
        :param a_e: initial easting
        :param a_n: initial northing
        """

        self.a_e = a_e
        self.a_n = a_n

    def complex_randb(self, r, b):
        """
        An equation that using imaginary numbers to calculate the coordinates of a new
        point from a range and bearing of an old point
        :param r: range from original coordinate to new coordinate
        :param b: bearing from original coordinate to new coordinate
        """

        # -b is required as geodetic bearings are opposite to mathematical bearings
        t = complex(cos(radians(-b)), sin(radians(-b))) * complex(0, r)
        delta_easting = t.real
        delta_northing = t.imag

        new_easting = self.a_e + delta_easting
        new_northing = self.a_n + delta_northing

        return new_easting, new_northing
```

## Naming

Your parameter names `a_e`, `a_n`, `r`, and `b` are too short and cryptic.  You should used `easting` `northing`, `range`, and `bearing`.

`complex_randb` is also confusing.  The input is real, the output is real.  The fact that complex numbers are internally used is an internal detail irrelevant to the caller.  What is `randb`, some kind of random b?  Oh, `range_and_bearing`!  But it is not a range and bearing function, it is a new coordinate function:

```
    def new_coordinate(self, range, bearing):
        """Doc-string without the complex number internal detail mentioned"""
        ...
```

The class name `CmO` is also quite cryptic.  Is that "C minus O" because it runs "C-O" calculations?  You need a better class name.